# How to replace/update the Value of an Attribute in LDAP Directory using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, scripting, ldap

The entries in our companys Non-AD LDAP Server look like this:

```
uid = e145871
sn = Smith
givenName = John
department = Research & Development
department = Human Resource
```

And so on...

I've developed a PowerShell script to add specific attributes and values which is working just fine. Now I need to replace specific values but the issue is the identical attribute name. (In this case it's "department")

My goal is to replace "Research & Development" with "Something Else". If I run the following script it gets replaced but Human Resource is deleted as well. Is it possible to replace only one value without touching/deleting the other?

```
$r = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ModifyRequest
$r.DistinguishedName = "uid=e145871,ou=identities,ou=users,o=items,dc=company,dc=domain,dc=com"

$DirectoryRequest_value = New-Object "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttributeModification"
$DirectoryRequest_value.Name = "department"
$DirectoryRequest_value.Contains("Research & Development")
$DirectoryRequest_value.Operation = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttributeOperation]::Replace
$DirectoryRequest_value.Add("SomethingElse")

$r.Modifications.Add($DirectoryRequest_value)

$result = $connection.SendRequest($r)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP `Replace` operation replaces (or *overwrites*) the entire value of the attribute, including any existing values that might exist as part of a multi-valued attribute.

From [RFC4511 §4.6 - "Modify Operation"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511):

> ```
> -  operation: Used to specify the type of modification being
>    performed.  Each operation type acts on the following
>    modification.  The values of this field have the following
>    semantics, respectively:
>
>    [...]
>
>        replace: replace all existing values of the modification
>        attribute with the new values listed, creating the attribute
>        if it did not already exist.  A replace with no value will
>        delete the entire attribute if it exists, and it is ignored
>        if the attribute does not exist.
> ```

Instead, add two separate modifications to the request - one to add `"SomethingElse"` and one to remove `"Research & Development"`:

```
$targetObject = 'uid=e145871,ou=identities,ou=users,o=items,dc=company,dc=domain,dc=com'
$attributeName = 'department'
$oldValue = 'Research & Development'
$newValue = 'SomethingElse'

$request = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ModifyRequest]::new()
$request.DistinguishedName = $targetObject

# This modification will add the new value "SomethingElse"
$addNewDepartment = @{
    Name = $attributeName
    Operation = 'Add'
} -as [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttributeModification]
$addNewDepartment.Add($newValue) |Out-Null

$request.Modifications.Add($addNewDepartment) |Out-Null

# This modification will remove the old value "Research & Development"
$removeOldDepartment = @{
    Name = $attributeName
    Operation = 'Delete'
} -as [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttributeModification]
$removeOldDepartment.Add($oldValue) |Out-Null

$request.Modifications.Add($removeOldDepartment) |Out-Null

$result = $connection.SendRequest($request)
```